# Not attribute targeting an element

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm having some trouble working with the `:not()` pseudo-class, I'm starting to consider my goal to be unavailable within CSS alone.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggmVBy) of my work

What I am trying to achieve is the to make the first letter within the paragraph that are not within a the span to change.

```css
section p:not([span]):first-letter  {
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:'Cinzel Decorative';
}
```

```
<p><span>Unchanged text</span> Changed text</p> // Goal <---
```

I have both have tried and know that classes work, however that would require me to change a lot of previous code and would highly prefer the span element in this case. And since there is several paragraph sections it wouldn't be efficient to look for a value either.

Comment: `[span]` addresses an element with the `span` attribute--is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I guess, if I understood the question right, to clarify myself, since the span element is inside the paragraph element in the very beginning the content within the span would be the :first-letter, however I want it to exclude the span element and go for the first letter after the span closes.

Comment: Added a smaller html snippet that should expain it, otherwise the codepen link should cover it.

Comment: @Unkn0wn you want the `C` to be affected, correct? If so, see my answer.

Comment: Why are you marking up your subheadings as span elements within paragraphs in the first place? Considering you already do mark up your top-level heading with an h1, I feel like you're creating an unnecessary problem that could be avoided altogether just by marking things up correctly.

Comment: @Unkn0wn have u took a look at my answer?

Comment: @BoltClock I first of started with heading there as well, however noticed that the heading element removed my code so I would have to rename my css targeting ( section p ) to ( section h2 p ) and just figured id use span instead and that got me going with this :not() problem that intrigued me.

Comment: This would probably be easier if you used proper markup.

Comment: @dippas Yes I indeed did, you did indeed solve the problem by walking around it, I'm just considering if there is a better way of solving it, otherwise I'd know what to do

Comment: @Unkn0wn: It's still a valid question, however I don't think the code from your codepen was the best code to use to represent your question...

Comment: @BoltClock Might not be, however it was the code I had when I ran stumbled upon it, also the code where I want to solve specific problem. Even thought the problem is solved already with other solutions or redesigning it.

Comment: @Unkn0wn I got a solution using CSS, no layout changes, and no Firefox shenanigans either.

Comment: @zer00ne Awesome work, really love how different your solution was and how every possible problem was encountered, really great work man and thanks once again! :)

Comment: It's a challenging question and fun, so thank you, sir.:) I saw the Codepen finally (Codepen is too much for my iPhone) and I took a turn at it, I'm not exactly sure how you envisioned it, so let me know if I'm on the right track. or not. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to change a bit your markup, making it semantically correct,  you can achieve it by doing this below:

```css
section {
  max-width: 80%;
   margin: 10px auto; /* changed for demo */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}
section h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #C55757;
  font-family: 'Syncopate';
}
section h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: 'Syncopate';
  color: #C55757;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
}
section div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 47%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  margin-top: 2%;
}
section div:last-of-type {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
section p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Cinzel Decorative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative|Syncopate|Open+Sans+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <h1>Company Name</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>What we do
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec imperdiet tincidunt ornare. Quisque rutrum velit mi, eget aliquet turpis consectetur vel. Maecenas convallis nunc pulvinar urna placerat, nec tincidunt massa </p><p>Morbi quis vehicula leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id felis dapibus lectus auctor faucibus vitae vel urna. Vivamus vel dui elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Our company
    </h2>
    <p>Nunc eget odio sit amet lorem consequat dictum. In consequat, nunc at feugiat volutpat, lacus sapien mollis lectus, sed facilisis risus massa vel augue. Nam at tellus ac odio consectetur interdum ut et ex. Nullam in tincidunt nunc. Nunc tincidunt est eu neque molestie, vitae suscipit ante egestas. Cras id auctor arcu.</p><p>
Cras eget metus tincidunt, eleifend mi id, congue elit. Aenean faucibus est leo, nec rhoncus justo aliquam nec. Praesent erat erat, pellentesque at varius in, ultrices quis urna.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: "What we do" and "Our company" should be h2, not p. (I upvoted btw)

Comment: I just updated to that, I was thinking the exact same thing :p (Great minds think alike `;)` )

Comment: This is better markup indeed. You should still remove the `<br>` and use different `<p>`.

Comment: yes @Oriol indeed, that was just plain copy paste from OP `lorem ipsum`, I've updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 3**

I finally have my laptop (was using iPhone) and see the codepen, so here's my take on it.

- I wanted to change layout, but I didn't because there must be a method to the madness (Although I did change the content; See the last 2 items of this list.)
- The layout in general is the `display:table-*` group.
- The 2 sub headings? "What we do" and "Our work" are `::before` pseudo-elements.
- The `<span>` now serves as `:first-letter` since each browser's interpretation of `:first-letter` is too wacky we'll just pass on that.

[<kbd>**CODEPEN**</kbd>](http://codepen.io/01/pen/vgmOqL)

**EDIT**

OK, jumped the gun on Snippet 2, see Snippet 3 which is Snippet 2 **without** `first-letter`. `first-letter` is replaced by a pseudo-element `::before`. Beat that Firefox!

Details are commented in Snippet

**SNIPPET 3**

```css
/* position: absolute will take span out
|| of the flow. This means whatever affects 
|| the <span> directly will not affect the 
|| <p> and vice versa.
*/

/* ch is a measure unit equalling the width
||   of a zero. It's size is relative to
||   font-size. I find ch indispensible when
||   dealing with text.
*/

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -12ch;
}
/* Since :first-letter behaves differently than what's
|| desired in Firefox, we'll use a ::before pseudo-
|| and then position it over the 'C'
*/
/* We can adjust the line-height (/40%) to bring both <span> 
|| and <p> in vertical alignment. The left: 1.2ch is the 
|| space between <span> and <p>. The white background is
|| the hacky part which is used to hide the original
|| 'C'. Since the majority of the measurements (i.e. ch)
|| are relative,the setup is responsive as long as you
|| remeber that it's relative to font-size.
*/

p::before {
  content: 'C';
  font: 100 3ch/40% Times;
  color: red;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 1.2ch;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  left: 12ch;
}
```

```html
<!--All textNodes residing within <p> includes it's

descendant's textNodes as well. This is evident if we use

.textContent or jQuery .text(). Knowing that, we should

expect that a direct approach using CSS to change the 'C'

with pseudo-selector :first-letter would fail.-->




<p><span>Unchanged text</span> Changed text</p>


<!--Getting the <span> out of the way so that the :first-

letter will be 'C' instead of 'A' is the first step-->
```

---

---

**OLD**

**UPDATE 1**

See Snippet 2 I used `position:relative` and `absolute` so that the `<span>` is in a different flow from the rest. Got this idea from BoltClock's and Oriol's convo.

---

I was thinking: *What's the wackiest CSS property?* and I came up with this using `floats`

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
span {
  float: left
}
p:first-letter {
  font: 100 3ch/60% Times;
  color: red;
  float: left;
  padding-left: .5ch;
}
p {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Unchanged text</span> Changed text</p>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -12.5ch;
}
p:first-letter {
  font: 100 3ch/40% Times;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: .5ch;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  left: 12ch;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Unchanged text</span> Changed text</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox unfortunately. Firefox's implementation of ::first-letter is, in your words, "wacky". (To be fair, *everyone's* implementation of ::first-letter is wacky but Firefox's tends to stand out more than others. Chrome has this really ridiculous white-space bug with ::first-letter for example, described elsewhere on SO.)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted yes, however since it is the wackiest property it really screwed up the other parts of the design +1

Comment: Firefox has foiled me once more!

Comment: Is Firefox wacky? The [draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-first-letter) says "*The `::first-letter` pseudo-element represents the first typographic letter unit on the first formatted line of its originating element, if it is not preceded by any other content*". I think the  floated span is "any other content".

Comment: @Oriol: You left out the critical bit: "if it is not preceded by any other content (such as images or inline tables) **on its line**". Is a float part of a formatted line? That's the million-dollar question (to which Firefox's answer, apparently, is yes).

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, I missed that part. Yes, it's a good question; I guess floats are not entirely on the line because they are out-of-flow, but they behave a bit like if they were on the line

Comment: Speaking of flow, I was hoping using `position: relative` would've taken the `<span>` out of flow as `float` did. Is this flow different since the true space that a `relative` positioned element is it's original spot?

Comment: @zer00ne: position: relative does not remove an element from flow. It's very much like translate() in the sense that the element's position in layout remains the same even when you offset the element using relative positioning. For example if you shift the span 10px to the right and 10px down, the layout still acts as if the span were not shifted at all - and it still being in the flow is the reason why the layout continues to react to the span at all.

Comment: @zer00ne: Absolute positioning suffers from the same problem apparently, judging by the bug report.

Comment: Confirmed, absposing suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @BoltClock  Indeed you are correct, sir. I did away with the `:first-letter` since it's not cross-browser and used a `::before` pseudo-element instead. Then absposed the span and relposed the p and pseudo and not even Firefox can ruin it...right?